# Monitor Calico network policies behavior

Tags: kubernetes, calico

How could I monitor the network policies behavior?

I have a k8s cluster with calico as SDN.

For example I create a network policy to deny traffic from a set of IPs.

I try to make some executions from those IPs and they fail.

Where can I see that that traffic is being rejected because a Network policy?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such possibility by default, but you can try to follow this [instruction](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.1/getting-started/kubernetes/tutorials/stars-policy/) to create a user interface that shows blocked and allowed connections in real time.

Also, [Getting started with Calico](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.1/getting-started/) could be useful.

You can find Calico logs in the /var/log/calico folder on the Calico pod.

More about logging please find here: [Calico Logging](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.1/usage/troubleshooting/logging).